# Entity Framework code-first - adding a column that already exists in the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am using .NET Core 3.1.2 and Entity Framework Core 3.1.2.

Approach is code first, but I have one column in my SQL Server table that already exists (`Country`), and I don't have it in the entity class.

So I have added a plain string property

```
public string Country { get; set; }
```

Now, when I try to save this table (e.g. customer) I get an error:

> Invalid column name Customer_Country

I cannot create migration because the column already exists; is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please add the entity definition, the table DDL and any fluent mapping to the question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Code is proprietary, not sure that I can. But can you tell me, e.g. when entity code first is used, and column already exists in DB (I know, that's not good), what would be correct approach?

Comment: Change name of the class and post here. Looks like it is property of Owned Type.

Comment: Code first against an existing database works fine.  You just need to map the properties to the existing columns properly.

Comment: When I create Migration, it also creates column with table name, not just 'Country', but 'Tablename_country'. Sorry I cannot paste code. There is no Owned type, or owned attribute at all in code.

Comment: If you have an existing table, don't use migrations.

Comment: Even if I delete column manually from DB, and create migration, it still wants to name it Table_Country. If I change manually to 'Country', it creates column correctly, but I cannot save, it throws an error.

Comment: Sorry, I found owned property: builder.Entity<SomeTable>().OwnsOne(someTable => someTable.someTableAddress).Property(address => address.Country).HasColumnName("Country").IsRequired();  And this Address have also Country property. Could this be a problem?

Comment: You could scaffold your database schema to your code (Reverse Engineering: DB -> Code).
[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)